# gallery colorbox thumbnail issue

Tags: views, media, javascript

I've created an image gallery with colorbox and views like this tutorial. 
First image of the album is a thumbnail the others are content. So I want to display the thumbnail, when I click the thumbnail only show the other pictures except the thumbnail.

[http://www.wdtutorials.com/2013/03/06/drupal-7-tutorial-how-create-image-overlays-colorbox#.U2Eyi_l_v94](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADIJK.png)

I'v followed this tutorial excactly.

So far so good, but when I click my thumbnail the colorbox opens and shows my thumbnail and all the other images. The settings are the same as the video.

[image]

I have set the first image field the multi row settings display 1 item start 0
2nd image show all the other images and display all start 1

Can someone help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The colorbox module have given me a lot of headaches in the past. Shadowbox offers that functionality out of the box (and it looks a lot nicer without the hassle of theming it. https://drupal.org/project/shadowbox. I use version 4 myself on this site, see for an example how it looks:
[Click on the photo](https://schoolplaza.net/school/basisonderwijs/groningen/groningen/schoolplaza/fotos/schaatsen-op-de-schoolvijver)

Comment: I have 6 node gallery pages. How do you filter the content to show only the gallery of the specific node not the full content of all the node gallery pages?

Comment: If you switched to shadowbox you can go to your nodetype, in display options set imagefield to shadowbox and choose Linked to: Original image
as compact gallery field entity
with node title as caption

Comment: Is there a way to hide the first image when the shadowbox pops up? because i would use my first image for album cover and the others to display in the box